# Collaborate on Word or Excel documents stored on server

Tags: office365, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm searching a way of using either Office API or Google Realtime API, or whatever that can let me collaborate (or simply open in edit mode) a document (.doc, .docx, .xlsx, .xls) stored on my server (not on Google Drive, not on onedrive, not on the cloud, but on MY server).

Is something like that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

[Office Online Server](https://blogs.office.com/2016/05/04/office-online-server-now-available/) is the on premise version of Office Online.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Shared Workbooks in connection with a shared network drive. The technology is officially legacy since Office 2016 but its still available and I think the only way to collaborate on the same document on your side of the firewall. You might want to have a look at my recent blog post where I compare all available methods and their limitations: https://www.xltrail.com/blog/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks